# Where can I download ActiveMQ Source Distributions?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have been trying to download the source distributions for ActiveMQ now for over a week and all I get is a server not found page.  I have emailed Apache and have gotten no responses. At one point the mirrors site was taking me to a celebrity gossip website. I can get the binary distribution, but I need the source code. This is the link I have been trying

http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=%2Factivemq%2Fapache-activemq%2F5.4.0%2Factivemq-parent-5.4.0-source-release.tar.gz

Does anyone know what is going on with this?

Comment: WHere did you send email at Apache?

Comment: Well I posted to their forums and I keep getting emails from them saying they are still reviewing my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the broken links are resolved you can always get it from svn:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/tags/activemq-5.4.0/

Answer (score 5):

You can get it from:
http://www.apache.org/dist//activemq/apache-activemq/5.4.0/

Answer (score 1):

You can find active MQ core source code here:

http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.activemq/activemq-core/

Comment: Not familiar with this 'grepcode' site. I wouldn't download from it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the latest release, just follow the download link from their [page](http://activemq.apache.org/).

e.g. [here](http://apache.uib.no//activemq/apache-activemq/5.4.2/activemq-parent-5.4.2-source-release.zip)

Comment: She doesn't want the latest release, and the links are broken for 5.4.0.